# java.io.FileNotFoundException error in Apache Spark even though my file exists

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark, delta-lake, google-spark-operator

I'm new to spark and doing on POC to download a file and then read it. However, I am facing issue that the file doesn't exists.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/app/data-Feb-19-2023_131049.json does not exist

But when I printed the path of the file I find out the file exists and the path is also correct.

This is the output

```
23/02/19 13:10:46 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 10.14.142.21:37515 with 2.2 GiB RAM, BlockManagerId(1, 10.14.142.21, 37515, None)
FILE IS DOWNLOADED
['/app/data-Feb-19-2023_131049.json']
23/02/19 13:10:49 INFO SharedState: Setting hive.metastore.warehouse.dir ('null') to the value of spark.sql.warehouse.dir.
23/02/19 13:10:49 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is 'file:/app/spark-warehouse'.
23/02/19 13:10:50 INFO InMemoryFileIndex: It took 39 ms to list leaf files for 1 paths.
23/02/19 13:10:51 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 206.6 KiB, free 1048.6 MiB)
23/02/19 13:10:51 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 35.8 KiB, free 1048.6 MiB)
23/02/19 13:10:51 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on experian-el-d41b428669cc1e8e-driver-svc.environments-quin-dev-1.svc:7079 (size: 35.8 KiB, free: 1048.8 MiB)
23/02/19 13:10:51 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from json at <unknown>:0
23/02/19 13:10:51 INFO FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
23/02/19 13:10:51 INFO FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
23/02/19 13:10:51 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: json at <unknown>:0
23/02/19 13:10:51 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (json at <unknown>:0) with 1 output partitions
23/02/19 13:10:51 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0 (json at <unknown>:0)
23/02/19 13:10:51 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
23/02/19 13:10:51 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
23/02/19 13:10:51 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[2] at json at <unknown>:0), which has no missing parents
23/02/19 13:10:51 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 9.0 KiB, free 1048.6 MiB)
23/02/19 13:10:51 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 4.8 KiB, free 1048.5 MiB)
23/02/19 13:10:51 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on experian-el-d41b428669cc1e8e-driver-svc.environments-quin-dev-1.svc:7079 (size: 4.8 KiB, free: 1048.8 MiB)
23/02/19 13:10:51 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1513
23/02/19 13:10:51 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[2] at json at <unknown>:0) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0))
23/02/19 13:10:51 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks resource profile 0
23/02/19 13:10:51 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (10.14.142.21, executor 1, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4602 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
23/02/19 13:10:52 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on 10.14.142.21:37515 (size: 4.8 KiB, free: 2.2 GiB)
23/02/19 13:10:52 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 10.14.142.21:37515 (size: 35.8 KiB, free: 2.2 GiB)
23/02/19 13:10:52 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (10.14.142.21 executor 1): java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/app/data-Feb-19-2023_131049.json does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:779)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:1100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:769)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:976)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createInputStream(CodecStreams.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createInputStreamWithCloseResource(CodecStreams.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.MultiLineJsonDataSource$.dataToInputStream(JsonDataSource.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.MultiLineJsonDataSource$.createParser(JsonDataSource.scala:199)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.MultiLineJsonDataSource$.$anonfun$infer$4(JsonDataSource.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema.$anonfun$infer$3(JsonInferSchema.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithResource(Utils.scala:2763)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema.$anonfun$infer$2(JsonInferSchema.scala:86)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.nextCur(Iterator.scala:486)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:492)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.isEmpty(Iterator.scala:387)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.isEmpty$(Iterator.scala:387)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.isEmpty(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.reduceLeftOption(TraversableOnce.scala:249)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.reduceLeftOption$(TraversableOnce.scala:248)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.reduceLeftOption(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.reduceOption(TraversableOnce.scala:256)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.reduceOption$(TraversableOnce.scala:256)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.reduceOption(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema.$anonfun$infer$1(JsonInferSchema.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2(RDD.scala:855)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2$adapted(RDD.scala:855)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

23/02/19 13:10:52 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 1) (10.14.142.21, executor 1, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4602 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
23/02/19 13:10:52 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 1) on 10.14.142.21, executor 1: java.io.FileNotFoundException (File file:/app/data-Feb-19-2023_131049.json does not exist) [duplicate 1]
23/02/19 13:10:52 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 2) (10.14.142.21, executor 1, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4602 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
23/02/19 13:10:52 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 2) on 10.14.142.21, executor 1: java.io.FileNotFoundException (File file:/app/data-Feb-19-2023_131049.json does not exist) [duplicate 2]
23/02/19 13:10:52 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) (10.14.142.21, executor 1, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4602 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
23/02/19 13:10:52 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) on 10.14.142.21, executor 1: java.io.FileNotFoundException (File file:/app/data-Feb-19-2023_131049.json does not exist) [duplicate 3]
23/02/19 13:10:52 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
23/02/19 13:10:52 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
23/02/19 13:10:52 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 0
23/02/19 13:10:52 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Killing all running tasks in stage 0: Stage cancelled
23/02/19 13:10:52 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (json at <unknown>:0) failed in 1.128 s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) (10.14.142.21 executor 1): java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/app/data-Feb-19-2023_131049.json does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:779)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:1100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:769)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:976)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createInputStream(CodecStreams.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createInputStreamWithCloseResource(CodecStreams.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.MultiLineJsonDataSource$.dataToInputStream(JsonDataSource.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.MultiLineJsonDataSource$.createParser(JsonDataSource.scala:199)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.MultiLineJsonDataSource$.$anonfun$infer$4(JsonDataSource.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema.$anonfun$infer$3(JsonInferSchema.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithResource(Utils.scala:2763)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema.$anonfun$infer$2(JsonInferSchema.scala:86)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.nextCur(Iterator.scala:486)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:492)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.isEmpty(Iterator.scala:387)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.isEmpty$(Iterator.scala:387)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.isEmpty(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.reduceLeftOption(TraversableOnce.scala:249)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.reduceLeftOption$(TraversableOnce.scala:248)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.reduceLeftOption(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.reduceOption(TraversableOnce.scala:256)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.reduceOption$(TraversableOnce.scala:256)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.reduceOption(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JsonInferSchema.$anonfun$infer$1(JsonInferSchema.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2(RDD.scala:855)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2$adapted(RDD.scala:855)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is my code to download the file and and print its path

```
    def find_files(self, filename, search_path):
        result = []

        # Wlaking top-down from the root
        for root, dir, files in os.walk(search_path):
            if filename in files:
                result.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
        return result

    def downloadData(self, access_token, data):
        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Charset': 'UTF-8',
            'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'
        }

        try:
            response = requests.post(self.kyc_url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
            response.raise_for_status()
            logger.debug("received kyc data")
            response_filename = ("data-" + time.strftime('%b-%d-%Y_%H%M%S', time.localtime()) + ".json")
            with open(response_filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                json.dump(response.json(), f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
            f.close()
            print("FILE IS DOWNLOADED")
            print(self.find_files(response_filename, "/"))
        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
            logger.error("failed to fetch kyc data")
            raise SystemExit(err)
        return response_filename
```

This is my code to read the file and upload to minio

```
    def load(spark: SparkSession, json_file_path: str, destination_path: str) -> None:
        df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json(json_file_path)
        df.write.format("delta").save(f"s3a://{destination_path}")
```

I'm running spark in k8s with spark operator.

This is my SparkApplication manifest

```
apiVersion: "sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta2"
kind: SparkApplication
metadata:
  name: myApp
  namespace: demo
spec:
  type: Python
  pythonVersion: "3"
  mode: cluster
  image: "myImage"
  imagePullPolicy: Always
  mainApplicationFile: local:///app/main.py
  sparkVersion: "3.3.1"
  restartPolicy:
    type: OnFailure
    onFailureRetries: 3
    onFailureRetryInterval: 10
    onSubmissionFailureRetries: 5
    onSubmissionFailureRetryInterval: 20
  timeToLiveSeconds: 86400
  deps:
    packages:
      - io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.2.0
      - org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.1
  driver:
    env:
      - name: NAMESPACE
        value: demo
    cores: 2
    coreLimit: "2000m"
    memory: "2048m"
    labels:
      version: 3.3.1
    serviceAccount: spark-driver
  executor:
    cores: 4
    instances: 1
    memory: "4096m"
    coreRequest: "500m"
    coreLimit: "4000m"
    labels:
      version: 3.3.1
  dynamicAllocation:
    enabled: false
```

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong ?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that the file exists on all nodes? it could be that the file exists on the driver node but doing the actual load from executors they can't find the file.

It is better in cluster mode to keep the files on  a shared FS like HDFS

Comment: @IslamElbanna My understanding was all the execution will happen in executors not in driver. So, you are suggesting that probably the file is being downloaded in driver node and being uploaded in executor node. That would certainly explain my issue. However, is there a way to download in executor node ?

Comment: No, what I mean is that a file should be accessible from both driver and executors, so my question is: where is this file located?  on the local file system which means it will be accessible from the driver only? or on a shared FS like HDFS or S3 ?

Comment: It's local filesystem. So it will be accessible to driver only

Comment: Then this is probably the problem, if you are working on a cluster then the input files should be on a shared file system like HDFS or S3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running in cluster mode then you need your input files to be shared on a shared FS like `HDFS` or `S3` but not on local FS, since both of driver and executors should have access to the input file.

Comment: Yeah. I'm using minio now and that seems to fix my issue.

Comment: However, I ran into another issue. Now I am using minio as shared storage. So, in one folder path I am keeping the files and in another folder path I am creating the delta-lake entries.

Comment: But I'm getting the below error while trying save file.

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 7) (10.14.109.236 executor 1): java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.f of type scala.Function1 in instance of org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF
```

Comment: Code is the following

```
    def load(spark: SparkSession, file_path: str, destination_path: str) -> None:
        df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json(f"s3a://{file_path}")
        df.show()
        df.write.format("delta").mode("append").save(f"s3a://{destination_path}")
```
Any hint what went wrong ?

Comment: The code looks simple to me, I guess it is better to create another question with the full stacktrace, otherwise could you please accept the current answer to the question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75502059/java-lang-classcastexception-while-saving-delta-lake-data-to-minio/75502715#75502715